# How to change ASP.NET server control data via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In My ASP.NET page I'm having Gridview which contains ListBox.
options of listbox increases and decreases according to my business logic.
Now I'm changing listbox option from server side hence it takes more time(Even used UpdatePanel, still takes more time).

Now I want to do this functionality via Jquery. But When I change or add or increase options of listBox via Jquery then I cannot retrieve my change when my request is postback.

So my basic question is How to Edit Options of listbox (Server Control) Via Jquery and get those changes at server side.

Comment: You've never marked a single question you asked as answered

Comment: I did'nt get you @DenisWessels

Comment: When you ask questions on this site and get helpful answers you should up vote them and mark them as answered.You haven't marked any questions you asked in the past as answered

Comment: @DenisWessels I do vote up them, if I am satisfied with an answer.... Give me answer of this question And i will prove you. :)